# Instance method can't be accessed from static method

Tags: flutter, dart, static-methods

I have a boolean `bool isDriverAvailable=false` which will check if the user is online or not, if it is online then the `GeoFire` plugin will update its latitude and longitude to the database.
I am using a background location for this project which has a callback
 `static void backgroundLocationCallBack(LocationDto location)` method where I plan to implement this check and update the location.
this is my code so far

```
class _HomeTabPageState extends State<HomeTabPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, OSMMixinObserver {
  bool isDriverAvailable = false;

//some code

static void backgroundLocationCallBack(LocationDto location) async {
    print("from background location +${location.latitude}");
        if (isDriverAvailable)
        Geofire.setLocation(
            currentFirebaseUser!.uid, location.latitude!, location.longitude!);

  }

  void getLocationLiveUpdates() async {
    return await BackgroundLocator.registerLocationUpdate(
        backgroundLocationCallBack,
        autoStop: false,
        // disposeCallback: backgroundLocationDisposeCallBack,

        androidSettings: AndroidSettings(
            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.NAVIGATION,
            interval: 5,
            distanceFilter: 0,
            client: LocationClient.google,
            androidNotificationSettings: AndroidNotificationSettings(
              notificationChannelName: 'Location tracking',
              notificationTitle: 'Start Location Tracking',
              notificationMsg: 'Track location in background',
              notificationBigMsg:
                  'Background location is on to keep the app up-tp-date with your location. This is required for main features to work properly when the app is not running.',
              notificationIconColor: Colors.grey,
            )));
  }
```

I get an error on `if (isDriverAvailable)`
The error

```
Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.
Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method.
```

I can't remove the `static` keyboard on `backgroundLocationCallBack(LocationDto location)` as it is only meant to work with `static` method.
How else can I implement the bool check ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to somehow pass the `isDriverAvailable` boolean to your function, remove the `static` from the method, or refactor the whole thing.

Static members of a class need to be available from a class-level (in comparison to usual members being available on instance-level), which means that you don't get the implicit `this` member, as it is assumed you will call the function from the outside the instance.

I gave a quick glance to the `background_locator` package and its documentation, but nothing states this callback needs to be `static`, as long as it takes a LocationDto argument and returns void.

Comment: https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/issues/312#issuecomment-1086854822      . As discussed in this thread.

Comment: Sounds like the `background_locator` package got a problem with its implementation and null-safety there. I tried to think an idea extending LocationDto to add isDriverAvailable to it, but it won't work if you're forced to use a static method as the callback.

From there, the only solution you got is to make `isDriverAvailable` a `static` as well.

Comment: but then if i change it to `static bool isDriverAvailable =false` , then it will always be false? isn't it ? can I change the value to `true` tho ?

Comment: @Pannam You can change it, as long as it isn't const. You can just say `_HomeTabPageState.isDriverAvailable = true;` anywhere in your code. Do note though that because the class is private (as it begins with an underscore _ ), you won't be able to do it outside of the file it is defined in.